# Extend DataGrid ColumnHeaderStyle programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0, datagridcolumn

I'm defining the style of DataGridColumnHeader by ResourceDictionary with a Setter there:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
  <Setter Property="Background">
    <Setter.Value>
      <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,0" StartPoint="0,1">
```

and so on (not really important.

Now I want to extend the style by a tooltip for the ColumnHeader. I have to set this tooltip in code because it is different for some situations.

I could do it that way:

```
var style = new Style(typeof(System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DataGridColumnHeader));
style.Setters.Add(new Setter(ToolTipService.ToolTipProperty,"my tooltop"));
dgcol1.HeaderStyle = style;
```

But obviously all other style setters from the recource dictionary are overwritten then.
How can I add my tooltip to the ColumnHeader by code?
Does anyone have any idea? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try this one

```
<Style x:Key="baseStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
  <Setter Property="Background">
    <Setter.Value>
      <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,0" StartPoint="0,1">
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter Property="Background">
</Style>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}" BasedOn={StaticResource baseStyle}>
```

code behind

```
var style = new Style(typeof(System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DataGridColumnHeader));
style.BasedOn = this.TryFindResource("baseStyle") as Style;
style.Setters.Add(new Setter(ToolTipService.ToolTipProperty,"my tooltop"));
dgcol1.HeaderStyle = style;
```

hope this helps...